# Where can I find implementation code for the algorithm

Tags: algorithms, matlab, mathematica, collision-detection

I am trying to build a computer simulation for collision of 2 ellipsoids that translate and rotate with very high speed. (accuracy is more important then running speed)

is the article:

An Algebraic Approach to Continuous Collision Detection for Ellipsoids

https://hal-unice.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00646511/document

represent the best algorithm for this job?

if so, where can I find the computer program implement it (in any computer language, e.g. matlab,c++...)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried to work on $\det(x*B+A)$ instead of $\det(x*A+B)$ ?

Comment: yes, doesn't work, still the answers different from the one mentioned in the article